# Removing Flag in GCC using Pragma

Tags: gcc, pragma

I want to remove a compiler flag for a praticular file in my project. How to do this using `#pragma`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19431723/11107541

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that this is late, but I just ran into the same issue on my project.

I couldn't find a #pragma to modify the list of compiler flags, but I *could* use GNU Make's ability to modify make variables on a per-target basis.

One of my files was taking forever to compile with `-fvar-tracking-assignments` (which was added to -O2 a few releases back). I was looking for a way to turn that off for one file; after looking (in vain) for an appropriate pragma, I simply added this line to my makefile to modify `CXXFLAGS` when compiling and linking those specific files:

```
ObtuseObj.o ObtuseObjTest.o ObtuseObjTest : CXXFLAGS += -fno-var-tracking-assignments
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to others!

Answer (score 2):

Only flags that control warnings can be overridden using `#pragma`, see the [diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) documentation page.

For instance, you could do:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"
```

To make GCC ignore the warnings generated by mismatched formatting strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if gcc has such pragmas.  I can't find any on the [gcc page for pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html#Pragmas).

If you are asking a question related to gcc next time, tag it under gcc as well.  I would tag it but I can't.  Tagging under gcc would get you many more responses.