# Strict aliasing and arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, strict-aliasing

I have a function like this:

```
static void doSomething(int16_t array[256], int16_t mask, uint8_t skip){
    uint16_t storage = array[skip];
    uint64_t* array1=(uint64_t*)(array);
    uint64_t mask1 =0;
    uint16_t* Lmask=(uint16_t*)&mask1;
    Lmask[0]=mask;
    Lmask[1]=mask;
    Lmask[2]=mask;
    Lmask[3]=mask;
    int k;
    for (k =0 ; k < 64; k++) {
        array1[k]&=mask;
        array[skip]=storage;
        if(hasZero(array1[k])){
        ...
        }
    }
```

It should take an array of 16bit integers, apply a mask on it and check, whether it contains a 16 bit integer equaling to zero that is not on the skip position and if yes, do something. It all works fine till optimalisation -O2 is used (-O1,-Os functioning normally).

The function is called milions of times, therefore it can not use the 16bit mask and 16bit array because of effectivity. I suppose, the problem is, that this code is breaking the strict-aliasing rule. Is there any way, to say to the compilator, that array1 and array use the same memory location and thus it can't leave out the `array[skip]=storage;` before evaluating the if statement (I tried union, however with no succes, it did exactly the same as now)? Or is there any other way to do this so, that it wouldn't break this rule?

Comment: but do you really need O2?

Comment: As unfortunate as it is I do, the whole project is compiled using -O2 and I can't anything against it.

Comment: Your text says `g++` but your q is tagged [tag:C]

Comment: If `g++` is used then it is C++ code and should be tagged as c++ for this site

Comment: Now I have tested it on gcc and it shows ecactly the same behaviour, therefore I am leaving the g++ part out of the main text in order not to confuse with it.

Comment: Matt, sorry, that was a mistake while rewriting it here. Corrected (correct in the original code).

Comment: You can either break the code into two loops (from 0 to `skip` and from `skip+1` to 64), or you can swap between `array[skip]` and `array[63]`, run a loop from 0 to 63, and swap them again (but that is permitted depending on what you do inside the `if` statement).

Comment: The breaking is possible, and I might use it, thought it will cause some additional ifs, the swaping isn't. I might have phrased it wrongly, however I need to skip only the 16bit number, not also the 3 other numbers that are evaluated with it.

Comment: why cant you use `__may_alias__` where the alias is declared, see https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-03/msg00197.html

Comment: @camelccc thanks, that worked exatcly as I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this violates strict aliasing by using `uint16_t` and `uint64_t` lvalues to read the same region of storage.

A quick fix for gcc is to use `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

A reliable fix is to rewrite the code to not contain any aliasing violations. This may seem more cryptic at first, but in theory the compiler will see what's going on and generate optimal assembly if you write correct code.

Comment: Yeah, that I would like to do, however how to do this while leaving the work with 64bit numbers in it? If I leave it out it will be of course slower, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: "it will be of course slower" - benchmark it before making this assumption (or compare assembly)

Comment: Well I have tried to earlier and it seemed slower as to be expected.

Comment: Perhaps your code was incorrect; maybe start a new question with the code you tried asking for how it can be sped up

Comment: That however leaves the original question, whether it is possible to indicate to the compilator to not leave it out, if possible inside the code as I am not the one doing the final compilation.

Comment: @Rasty see 2nd paragraph of my answer. Not sure if gcc has a way to push compiler options from the source code. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431723/gcc-pragma-to-add-remove-compiler-options-in-a-source-file)