# gfortran compiler directive to add/remove compiler option

Tags: fortran, gfortran, compiler-options, compiler-directives

I would like to temporarily disable a gfortran compiler option for a piece of Fortran code. I am looking for something like:

```
!GFORTRAN$ PUSH_OPTION(-fcheck=bounds)
SUBROUTINE FOO(BAR)
    INTEGER BAR(*)
    ! ...
END SUBROUTINE FOO
!GFORTRAN$ POP_OPTION
```

It [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19431723/1800052) gcc/g++ do not have such compiler directive. Is that possible to achieve that with gfortran?

Comment: I have not heard of any such directive for GCC.

Comment: You can compile certain modules with different flags, though, but I don't know how that works when, for example, a module containing an array is compiled with bounds checking but the module using the array isn't. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Ross, I'd like to be able to disable bounds checking only for specific places inside subroutines.

Comment: That's a pretty convoluted use case, in my opinion. The typical workflow is to compile everything with bounds checking (and other compile-time and run-time checks) when developing the code. Then, when you think everything is working right, you switch to production with faster execution times.